# How to share or save Audio after Effects, like altering pitch or rate?

Tags: ios, swift, audio, save, share

Basically, what i need here is that, after my app has recorded an audio, I have written code that alters its pitch and/or rate, And I use Activity View Controller, to share the audio from the app to other medias. But, what happens, when I share it is that, the "Original Recorded" audio is shared, instead of the audio that had "Effects" to it like rate or pitch. So, I do i go about sharing (itd be awesome, if you could also tell me how to save then share) the audio.

Example code:

```
//For fast rate playback

@IBAction func fasterAudio(sender: UIButton) {
    audioEngine.reset()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0   
    audioPlayer.rate = 1.75
    audioPlayer.play()
}

//For higher Pitch

@IBAction func highPitchAudio(sender: UIButton) { 
    audioPlayer.stop()
    audioEngine.stop()
    audioEngine.reset()
    audioPlayer.currentTime = 0

    var audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)

    var changePitchEffect = AVAudioUnitTimePitch()
    changePitchEffect.pitch = 1000
    audioEngine.attachNode(changePitchEffect)

    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: changePitchEffect, format: nil)
    audioEngine.connect(changePitchEffect, to: audioEngine.outputNode, format: nil)

    audioPlayerNode.scheduleFile(audioFile, atTime: nil, completionHandler: nil)
    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

    audioPlayerNode.play()
}
```

Please tell me how I can save and/or share the audio after it has been altered.
Whenever, i share it through UIActivityViewController, the original "audioFile" is shared, how do i share the altered audio?

Comment: did you recieve any solution ? I'm in a situation like this @BustedAJ

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: did you find any solution ?